# Take a picture instead of uploading one in Cognito Forms

Tags: cognito-forms

Is there an option that allows me to take a picture directly from the form, instead of uploading one? I’ve search in the *Build* menu and haven’t found anything like that.

Answer (score 3):

I am a developer with [Cognito Forms](https://www.cognitoforms.com).

The file upload field supports taking pictures when used on mobile devices.  When you click upload, you will have different options depending on the type of phone and apps installed, but all major phone platforms include support for selecting the camera as a source for the file.

Just add this field to your form and give it a try.